# What's the difference between care and care about?

Tags: differences

I want to know if there is any distinction between care and care about. For instance, I often say 'What do I care about?' rather than 'What do I care?'. I looked up the Merriam-Webster dictionary and it did not help. It seems care and care about are almost the same. Sure I know in care about, care is an intransitive verb.

My possibly wrong guess is that care about puts more emphasis on the object that we care while care is very much focused on the verb itself.

'What do I care about' is really weird like you guys said. It should be 'What does somebody else care about?'. My bad :).

Comment: "What do I care?" is a common idiom.  "What do I care about?" sounds like a rhetorical question.

Comment: It would be a bit weird to say *"What do I care about?"* - that's asking someone else to tell you *what things you care about*. Presumably you should know better than them! But *"What do I care?"* doesn't request an answer at all - it's an informal version of the rhetorical question *"**How much** do I care?"*, with the implied answer *"Not a lot - in fact, probably not at all"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"care" implies a much more general feeling or emotion.  "care about" almost always has a more specific object/target.

You'd likely hear someone say:  "I could care less".    You'd virtually never hear someone say "I could care less about" **unless** it's followed by an object.

Comment: You need more than 1 point!  +1

Comment: I think that's mainly the American version (which I must admit still sounds totally nonsensical to me, even after repeated exposure). The British version is *"I **couldn't** care less"*. Whenever I hear the US one I always think *"Well why **don't** you care less, since you're plainly not interested?"*

Comment: We Americans care so little that we leave the 'not' out.

Comment: @Oldcat I love it! :D

Comment: I found this online:Wrong slang. It's supposed to be "I couldn't care less" - because I have no interest. "I could care less" means there is some interest.

Comment: I don't mean to offend. I found an interesting post here--'I could care less' is an expression that idiots use when they don't care about something or have no interest in something. what they really mean is "i couldn't care less"

Comment: Yes - in the US, "I could care less" and "I could not care less" mean the **same** thing.

Comment: Two countries separated by a common language.  Very few things I enjoy more than dissecting the differences between ENU and EN-gb  ;-)

Comment: @Appalachian: The non-negated version sounds nonsensical to me simply because I'm *British* (I grew up with the negated version, and still hear/use it far more often). Oldcat is being a bit flip, but the US version is a perfectly natural usage to many Americans, with no implication that the speaker is an idiot. As it happens, I just watched Polanski's excellent "kitchen sink drama" [Carnage](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1692486/) last night, wherein Christoph Waltz's obviously highly-intelligent and carefully-spoken character says *"What are you telling him this for? **He could care less**."*

Answer (score 0):

"What do I care about" is a strange thing to say out loud.  It implies you are asking yourself to list things that you care about...kittens, bunnies, flowers, etc.

"What do I care" is a dismissive statement to another person showing your disinterest in the subject they are talking about.

Comment: Thank you! 'What do I care about' is indeed weird! It should be 'What do you care about?' :). Thanks again.